# PROJ Helmert temporal ETRF2000 to ITRF2014

Tags: proj, cs2cs

Just installed PROJ (Rel. 8.2.1) and GDAL (3.4.3), so apologies for my newbie questions as not found many examples of time based transformations. I have a FILE with the following coordinates in ETRF2000 that I am transforming to ITRF2014 (in LONG/LAT format):

**0.84179704711 51.15581584713 101.250 2023.0861**

I have transformed this by two independent means and get the following in UTM 31N:

**349075.701 E  5669367.399 N**

My understanding in PROJ, is that I can use the following to perform the same action:

```
cs2cs EPSG:7931 EPSG:9000 -f "%.11f" FILE_LONGLAT | proj +proj=utm +zone=31 -f "%.4f"
```

However, the result I get is:

**349075.391 E 5669367.639 N**

When I check using projinfo it returns the correct transformation parameters:

PROJ string:

```
+proj=pipeline
  +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1
  +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +z_in=m +xy_out=rad +z_out=m
  +step +proj=cart +ellps=GRS80
  +step +inv +proj=helmert +x=0.0547 +y=0.0522 +z=-0.0741 +rx=0.001701
        +ry=0.01029 +rz=-0.016632 +s=0.00212 +dx=0.0001 +dy=0.0001 +dz=-0.0019
        +drx=8.1e-05 +dry=0.00049 +drz=-0.000792 +ds=0.00011 +t_epoch=2010
        +convention=position_vector
  +step +inv +proj=cart +ellps=GRS80
  +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg
  +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1
```

So I am at a bit of a loss as to why the cs2cs output does not agree with my existing calculations (which have been independently verified).

---

I am not sure which way around the Lat/Long is supposed to be in the input. Using the answer below and a one liner I get the same answer, but this is in WGS84 at the end (which is not want I want).

```
cs2cs EPSG:7931 EPSG:9000 -f "%.11f" FILE_LATLONG | cs2cs EPSG:9000 EPSG:32631 -f "%.11f"
```

Answer (score 2):

I get the results that you expect with Proj version Rel. 9.1.1, December 1st, 2022. Here step by step (had to turn the coordinates, I suppose these lat-lon values present the correct place).

```
cs2cs EPSG:7931 EPSG:9000 -f "%.11f"

51.15581584713 0.84179704711 101.250 2023.0861
51.15582142444  0.84180482306 101.27049125079 2023.0861

cs2cs EPSG:9000 EPSG:32631 -f "%.11f"

51.15582142444  0.84180482306 101.27049125079 2023.0861
349075.70134043414      5669367.39904001076 101.27049125079 2023.0861
```

Comment: Okay, I am thoroughly confused now. Thought the format was Long, Lat, Height, Decimal_Year. You have gone from ITRF14 to WGS84 UTM31N, when I want the end result to be in ITRF14 UTM31N.

Comment: cs2cs wants nowadays coordinates in the same order than they are defined in the EPSG registry. Also the EPSG:4326 examples https://proj.org/apps/cs2cs.html show that. The rest in my answer can be totally wrong, I was just experimenting with your coordinates and got satisfied when I saw the desired values. I do not master the temporal CRSs at all. I guess I will delete my answer tomorrow. But check your GDAL and Proj versions and tell them in your question, they are important.

Comment: I would keep the answer as it does give a good example (albeit not the one I needed!). For info, my proj version is 8.2.1 (Ubuntu 22.04.01 WSL)